# Socket Programming : Inputstream Stuck in loop - read() always return 0

Tags: java, sockets

Server side code

```
public static boolean sendFile() {
        int start = Integer.parseInt(startAndEnd[0]) - 1;
        int end = Integer.parseInt(startAndEnd[1]) - 1;
        int size = (end - start) + 1;

        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(initSocket.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(byteArr,start,size);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            initSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Send file to : " + initSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            disconnected();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Client Side

```
public boolean receiveFile() {
        int current = 0;

        try {
            int bytesRead = bis.read(byteArr,0,byteArr.length);
            System.out.println("Receive file from : " + client);
            current = bytesRead;
            do {
                 bytesRead =
                 bis.read(byteArr, current, (byteArr.length-current));
                 if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead != -1);
            bis.close();
            bos.write(byteArr, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            disconnected();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Client side is multithreading,server side not use multithreading. I just paste some code that made problem if you want see all code please tell me.

After I debug the code, I found that if I set max thread to any and then the first thread always stuck in this loop. That `bis.read(....)` always return 0. Although, server had close stream and it not get out of the loop. I don't know why ... But another threads are work correctly.

```
do {
     bytesRead =
     bis.read(byteArr, current, (byteArr.length-current));
     if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead != -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How large is your input file (the one you send?) and how large is "byteArr"?
Also, by the time your check how many bytes are read, you already called bis.read(..) twice:

```
    int bytesRead = bis.read(byteArr,0,byteArr.length);
```

You probably want to read/send files larger than your buffer, so you probably want to do something like this:

```
        byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        int totalLength = 0;

        while(-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(buffer))) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalLength += bytesRead;
        }
        bos.close();
        is.close();
```

"is" would be a plain InputStream, Peter is right, you do not need to buffer it.

Comment: I have a question.
Why you set buffer size equal to 4096? Does other number not good than this ?

Comment: You could use almost any number here, 4k is (or today rather was) the default page size in memory, so it did not make sense to allocate less space because the OS allocated 4k anyway.

Answer (score 2):

read() will return 0 when you give it a buffer with no room left. (Which appears to be the case here)

I would suggest you use a DataInputStream.readFully() which does this for you.

```
dis.readFully(byteArr); // keeps reading until the byte[] is full.
```

If you are only writing large byte[] or only writing one piece of data, using a Buffered Stream just adds overhead.  You don't need it.

BTW: When you call close() it will call flush() for you.

Comment: It works with first thread that it doesn't stuck but another threads it catch a java.io.EOFException.
`dis.readFully(byteArr);
bis.close();
bos.write(byteArr);
bos.flush();
bos.close();`

Comment: On which statement? Are you trying to write to `bos` after closing it?

Comment: it cause exception on this line `dis.readFully(byteArr);` with thread n>1.

Comment: The number of threads shouldn't matter unless you are trying to share an input stream between threads.  This is not a good idea. Use only one thread for reading.